# #Twilio how to opt out any phone number

Tags: numbers, sms, twilio

Is there any way to add number in twilio's STOP list?

We require to add subscriber phone number in the STOP list manually or programing Function?

Scenario,
There is one of our customers, a very old lady, she has been subscribed to our promo messages, but now she does not want to receive any sms from us, because she is being charged for receiving messages.

At the same time she can not send STOP sms back to us.

Is there any way we can manually add this lady's number so that she should not be able to receive any message generated for this specific number?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't a way that you can add to the list, but send an email to support@twilio.com and they can manually add it.

Hope that helps.